# How to deploy the React SPA template in Visual Studio 17.8 Preview 1?

Tags: c#, reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core, vite

Yesterday, the Visual Studio team released two much welcome improvements in 17.8 Preview 1:

1. [The React and ASP.NET Core Visual Studio template supports TypeScript.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2022-17-8-preview-1-has-arrived/#new-react-typescript-and-asp-net-combined-templates)
2. [The React and ASP.NET Core Visual Studio template supports Vite.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2022-17-7-now-available/#supporting-vite-for-react-and-vue-new-project-creation)

However, I wasn't able to get the new template to deploy using the self-contained deployment option (.NET version 8.0.0 is not yet supported by the Azure Web App Service).

I tried the Build | Publish... option in Visual Studio... and (after provisioning new resources in Azure) received a 404 error when launching the site.

I've written a [very detailed post](https://mindline.com/august-15-authenticating-apps-in-2023-a-closer-look/) on deploying the existing `dot net react` version of this template for applications performing enterprise authentication. I want to update this post with the recently released preview template once I deploy and successfully run in Azure.

I *suspect* the problem is that the new preview template .CSPROJ files are much less detailed than the previous template .CSPROJ file. Here is the previous .CSPROJ that has the important looking PublishRunWebpack target:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web"> 
<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
<TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
<IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
<SpaRoot>ClientApp\</SpaRoot><DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(SpaRoot)node_modules</DefaultItemExcludes>
<SpaProxyServerUrl>https://localhost:3000</SpaProxyServerUrl>
<SpaProxyLaunchCommand>npm start</SpaProxyLaunchCommand>
<ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy" Version="7.0.8" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="2.13.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph" Version="2.13.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="2.13.2" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
<!-- Don't publish the SPA source files, but do show them in the project files list -->
<Content Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
<None Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
<None Include="$(SpaRoot)**" Exclude="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="DebugEnsureNodeEnv" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And !Exists('$(SpaRoot)node_modules') ">
<!-- Ensure Node.js is installed -->
<Exec Command="node --version" ContinueOnError="true">
  <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
</Exec>
<Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />
<Message Importance="high" Text="Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This may take several minutes..." />
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
</Target>

<Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
<!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build" />

<!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
<ItemGroup>
  <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)build\**" />
  <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
    <RelativePath>wwwroot\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</RelativePath>
  <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
  </ResolvedFileToPublish>
</ItemGroup>
</Target>
</Project>
```

And here are the .CSPROJ files in the new preview template:

CLIENT

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Sdk/0.5.105-alpha">
<PropertyGroup>
<StartupCommand>npm run dev</StartupCommand>
<JavaScriptTestRoot>src\</JavaScriptTestRoot>
<JavaScriptTestFramework>Jest</JavaScriptTestFramework>
<!-- Allows the build (or compile) script located on package.json to run on Build -->
<ShouldRunBuildScript>false</ShouldRunBuildScript>
<!-- Command to create an optimized build of the project that's ready for publishing -->
<ProductionBuildCommand>npm run build</ProductionBuildCommand>
<!-- Folder where production build objects will be placed --><BuildOutputFolder>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\dist</BuildOutputFolder>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

SERVER

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
<ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
<InvariantGlobalization>true</InvariantGlobalization>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi" Version="8.0.0-preview.7.23375.9" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.4.0" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
<ProjectReference Include="..\vitetypescriptreact.client\vitetypescriptreact.client.esproj">
  <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
</ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I've submitted the feedback through Visual Studio and left a comment on the announcement post: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2022-17-8-preview-1-has-arrived/#comment-29228

I'll post what I learn. Is the answer obvious to anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preview template has two issues:

1. Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy (8.0.0-preview.7.23375.9) fails to load, has been removed from the template, and, thus, apps built with the template require manual retries at launch
2. the .CSPROJ files are missing elements needed for Azure deployment ([reported to Microsoft and "under investigation"](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/React-and-ASPNET-Core-template-404-when/10437977)).

We could workaround the issue by:

1. downgrading to the latest stable spa proxy
2. updating the template HTML accordingly
3. adding necessary deployment logic to CSPROJ files

But I figure I will stick with the released template and upgrade it to Vite and TypeScript myself. Here is [my detailed walkthrough](https://mindline.com/august-15-authenticating-apps-in-2023-a-closer-look/).